# Vectorize numpy indexing and apply a function to build a matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have a matrix X of size (d,N). In other words, there are N vectors with d dimensions each. For example,

```
X = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

there are N=4 vectors of d=2 dimensions.

Also, I have rag array (list of lists). Indices are indexing columns in the X matrix. For example,

```
I = [ [0,1], [1,2,3] ]
```

The I[0]=[0,1] indexes columns 0 and 1 in matrix X. Similarly the element I[1] indexes columns 1,2 and 3. Notice that elements of I are lists that are not of the same length!

What I would like to do, is to index the columns in the matrix X using each element in I, sum the vectors and get a vector. Repeat this for each element of I and thus build a new matrix Y. The matrix Y should have as many d-dimensional vectors as there are elements in I array. In my example, the Y matrix will have 2 vectors of 2 dimensions.

In my example, the element I[0] tells to get columns 0 and 1 from matrix X. Sum the two vectors 2-dimensional vectors of matrix X and put this vector in Y (column 0). Then, element I[1] tells to sum the columns 1,2 and 3 of matrix X and put this new vector in Y (column 1).

I can do this easily using a loop but I would like to vectorize this operation if possible. My matrix X has hundreds of thousands of columns and the I indexing matrix has tens of thousands elements (each element is a short lists of indices).

My loopy code :

```
Y = np.zeros( (d,len(I)) )
for i,idx in enumerate(I):
    Y[:,i] = np.sum( X[:,idx], axis=1 )
```

Comment: Share your loopy code if you have implemented?

Comment: @Divakar added my loopy code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach -

```
# Get a flattened version of indices
idx0 = np.concatenate(I)

# Get indices at which we need to do "intervaled-summation" along axis=1
cut_idx = np.append(0,map(len,I))[:-1].cumsum()

# Finally index into cols of array with flattend indices & perform summation
out = np.add.reduceat(X[:,idx0], cut_idx,axis=1)
```

Step-by-step run -

```
In [67]: X
Out[67]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [15,  6, 17,  8]])

In [68]: I
Out[68]: array([[0, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3]], dtype=object)

In [69]: idx0 = np.concatenate(I)

In [70]: idx0 # Flattened indices
Out[70]: array([0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])

In [71]: cut_idx = np.append(0,map(len,I))[:-1].cumsum()

In [72]: cut_idx # We need to do addition in intervals limited by these indices
Out[72]: array([0, 4, 7])

In [74]: X[:,idx0]  # Select all of the indexed columns
Out[74]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  4,  2,  3,  4,  2,  3,  4],
       [15, 17,  8,  6, 17,  8,  6, 17,  8]])

In [75]: np.add.reduceat(X[:,idx0], cut_idx,axis=1)
Out[75]: 
array([[10,  9,  7],
       [46, 31, 25]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind explaining shortly what each line does (before I go lookup the functions)?

Comment: @Divakar, if i wanted to return just the values in the last step instead of summing, what would be the function instead of `np.add.reduceat`. So with the OP's `X` and `I` examples i would want the output: `[[1, 2], [6, 7, 8]]`